# Learning ManytoMany Field in Django

Tags: django, many-to-many

Hi I'm a Django newbie writing my first application. I have a basic model:

```
from django.db import models
from django_extensions.db.fields import AutoSlugField

class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    slug = AutoSlugField(populate_from='name', unique=True)

class Listings(models.Model):
    listing = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=75)
    tag = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

def __unicode__(self):
        return self.listing
```

I've added a few tags from terminal but all are surfacing as `Tag Object`. How do I get the name of the tag to show?

Also, how would I enable the admin to add tags, instead of adding via terminal each time?

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were missing a [`unicode`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#unicode) attribute in the `Tag` model

```
class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    slug = AutoSlugField(populate_from='name', unique=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "%s"% self.name
```

Also, Fix the indentation of your `unicode` block for `Listings` model

```
class Listings(models.Model):
    listing = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=75)
    tag = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.listing
```

Comment: Also, do you know how I could enable the admin to add tags so I don't have to do it in terminal? Thanks again for your help!